# How can i RequestMapping regex disable any word?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

i use spring boot + angularjs. Since I am using a single page application, I redirect all requests to index.html.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**/{[path:[^\\.]*}")
public String redirect() {
    return "forward:/";
}
```

**Problem**

I do not want to include end points like 'api' in this orientation. How can I do that?

for example endpoint : http://localhost:8080/application/api/getUsers

Comment: if you dont have much url to filter then you can use request mapping with multiple uris.

Comment: Just handle redirection from the client.
What happens if in the future you want to develop a mobile app that is not single page?

Comment: @Saiprateek Can we use the negative matching in regex? For example, redirect those who do not have the word 'api'.

Comment: @desoss I do not quite understand what you're talking about.